# Is there a way to separate elements of a list by order when theyre in a string format?

Tags: python

```
x=input()
x=list(x)
amtcrs=''.join(x[0:x.index(' ')])
amtst=''.join(x[x.index(' ')+1:])
a=0
b=''
while a<int(amtst):
    crsname=input()
    crsname=list(crsname)
    crs=''.join(crsname[0:crsname.index(' ')])
    st=''.join(crsname[crsname.index(' ')+1:])
    st=st.lower()
    a=a+1
    b=b+crs+st+' '
b=b.strip()
z=b.split(' ')
z.sort()
for l in range(0,int(amtcrs)):
    print(z)
```

This is what I've come up with for now. It's incomplete but I'm getting there.

Basically what I've been tasked to do is to first take an input "n m" such that n is the amount of courses that will be taught, and m is the amount of students that will be applying to the courses.

Then I have to take in m lines of input so that each line is a number followed by a name, the number being which course the student wants to take (number will be `1<= x >=n`) and the name of student.

for example:

if the input is 2 4, there will be 4 more inputs, lets say they are (1 david, 2 john, 2 Kevin, 1 jennifer)

What I must output is, in this case, 2 lines of the names of people enrolling in each course, with the people enrolling in course 1 being the first line of output and so on.

so the output here should be:

```
david jennifer
john Kevin
```

The tricky part is that if a person's name is similar to another person's name (i.e same length and at most 1 character different, mike and tike are similar, Mike and mime are similar (M and m count as the same char)) and they're applying to the same course, then whoever's name was inputted first would be registered for the course while the other one isn't.

For example: input is 3 4, then the next 4 inputs are ( 1 david, 1 davin, 2 john, 2 lola)

then the output should be:

```
david
john lola
```

also notice how the third line is empty because there is a third course but no one is signing up for it.

Comment: note: the output is supposed to be 
david
john lola

with the third line empty cuz there is nobody enrolled in 3rd course but it exists

Comment: `n,m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]`.  This will split on whitespace by default, and convert each element into an integer.

Comment: you overcomplicated it - don't convert to `list()`

Comment: you could create dictionary with lists and fill it `{1: ['david', 'jennifer'], 2: ['john', 'Kevin']}` and later display values from dictionary (every list in separated line)

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for that. do you have any tips on how I could split my outputs into n amount of lines? so if my inputs were "1 john 2 david 2 davin 1 bob" i split it into two lines of output first one being: " john bob" second one being: "david". also, i still haven't figured out how to do that part too, since david and davin are same length, same course and only 1 char difference (d and n), then only david gets into the course while davin wont be outputted.

Comment: @furas thanks for that idea, but im not sure how to implement that, if my inputs were "1 david 2 jennifer 1 john 2 Kevin" any tips on how to separate them into 1 david 1 john and 2 jennifer 2 Kevin so that i could use the dictionary?

Comment: simply use `data = "1 david 2 jennifer 1 john 2 Kevin".split(' ')` and you get list `data = ["1", "david", "2", "jennifer", "1", "john", "2", "Kevin"]` and later you can get pairs `data[0], data[1]` and `data[2], data[3]`, ... `data[len(data)-2], data[len(data)-1]`

Comment: if you get every person as separated line then simply `course, name = crsname.split(' ')` (without `list()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicated it - and all code seems useless.

You should get text from `input()` and directly use `.split(' ')` (without using `list()`)

And later you could put data in dictionary to create ie.`{'1': ['david', 'jennifer'], '2': ['john', 'Kevin']}` and next you should use `for`-loop to get lists with names and display them in line using `" ".join(list)`.

Something like this (but not tested)

```
# --- get numbers ---

x = input()

n, m = x.split(' ')
#n = int(n)
m = int(m)

# --- get courses and names ---

data = {}  # dict()

for _ in range(m)
    line = input()
    course, name = line.split(' ')
    
    if course not in data:
        data[course] = []  # list()
        
    if name not in data[course]:
        data[course].append(name)
    
#print(data)

# --- display results ---

#for key, value in data.items():
#    print( " ".join(value) )
    
for key in sorted(data.keys()):
    value = data[key]
    print( " ".join(value) )
```

Comment: thanks for this. 
one more thing, the code you've showed already aligns them by course and in the order they were inputted, now i need to figure out how to delete the ones that are similar, like (1 john and 1 JOHT) are similar cuz they have they same length and only have one letter difference (in this case similar = same length and 1 letter diff) so only john makes it into course 1, so would it be useful to first (lower()) all inputs to get rid of caps then if their lengths are equal and their courses are equal then compare letter for letter? but I'm not sure how to do that without imports.

Comment: if one char can be different (but other chars are in the same places) then use something like `count = 0` and `for char1, char2 in zip(name1, name2): if char1 != char2: count +=1`. and later check `if count<2: print("the same")` But if char can be in different place then it can make problem. And you have to use two `for`-loops to compare all names on list - `for number1, name1 in enumerate(data[key]): for number2,  name2 in enumerate(data[key]): if numbe1 != number2: ... here compare names ...`

Comment: have a look at this sample output, maybe this will clear up what I'm trying to figure out to do, notice the 3 lines of output being in that order with the course 1 students first, even though a course 3 student was inputted first. and notice that Jin was removed because it was too similar to jun but Li and ALI don't conflict because they arent same length.

Sample Input 2:
3 16
3 jun
3 Jin
1 Li
2 Kitty
2 Josh
3 Bob
1 Dave
2 Jose
1 David
3 Rob
3 Anne
3 Ann
2 Kevin
2 Lara
1 ALI
3 Xin
Sample Output 2:
Li Dave David ALI ///
Kitty Josh Kevin Lara ///
jun Bob Anne Ann Xin

Comment: better create new question on new page - you will have more place to write code and examples, and more new people will see it - so you more people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Enter course number,max student number ") # 3 4
course_student = str(input())

total_number_of_courses=course_student.split()[0]
max_student = course_student.split()[1]

hash_list= {str(course_id):[] for course_id in range( 1,int(total_number_of_courses))}
print("Enter course_id and name")
stu_course_ids=str(input())  #1 John, 2 Doe, 2 Johny

for stu_course_id in stu_course_ids.split(","):
    course_stu = stu_course_id.split(" ")
    course_stu = [ item for item in course_stu if item]
    if hash_list[course_stu[0]]:
        hash_list[course_stu[0]].append(course_stu[1])
    else:
       hash_list[course_stu[0]] = [course_stu[1]] 
       
for key, value in  hash_list.items():
    print( f"course_id: {key}  students: {' '.join(value)}")
```

my result:

```
course_id: 1  students: John
course_id: 2  students: Doe Johny
```